# d3js graph retaining old axis data on refreshing with new data

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, svg, d3.js

Here is a picture of my problem
[image]

Every time try to refresh my d3js graph with new data, its x axis and y axis gets messed up with both old and new axis.In the picture on the y axis 3,2.5,2,1.5 .... was my old axis and 800,700,600.....was my new axis.Similarly with the x axis
Can any one tell me wat i'm doing wrong.I only want the new axis to show up.
Here is my d3js code.

```
function ShowGraph(data) {

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH = 500,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 30
    },
    xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.year;
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.year;
    })]),
    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.count;
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.count;
    })]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
    .scale(xRange) // set the range of the axis
    .tickSize(5) // height of the ticks
    .tickSubdivide(true), // display ticks between text labels
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
    .scale(yRange) // set the range of the axis
    .tickSize(5) // width of the ticks
    .orient("left") // have the text labels on the left hand side
    .tickSubdivide(true); // display ticks between text labels
var transition = vis.transition().duration(1000).ease("exp-in-out");

transition.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
transition.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);




vis.append("svg:g") // add a container for the axis
.attr("class", "x axis") // add some classes so we can style it
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")") // move it into position
.call(xAxis); // finally, add the axis to the visualisation

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);


var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data)
circles.enter()
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xRange(d.year);
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yRange(d.count);
})
    .style("fill", "red")

circles.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xRange(d.year);
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yRange(d.count);
})
    .attr("r", 10)

circles.exit()
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .remove();
```

}

Here is it have a look. [link](http://bigquerymashup.appspot.com/ajaxPage) Try with word "the,and,i,and,the" one at a time

Comment: The selected answer here did not work for me when I had axis plus other data persisting. The selected answer to the following question fixed my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452112/nvd3-clear-svg-before-loading-new-chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to empty the axis before build the graph

```
function ShowGraph(data) {
    d3.selectAll('.axis').remove();
    var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    //...
```

EDIT
OK maybe I found the solution

The problem is the axis that appends every time to call the function.

So, if you add a check like so:

```
var hasAxis = vis.select('.axis')[0][0];

if(!hasAxis) {
   vis.append("svg:g") // add a container for the axis
   .attr("class", "x axis") // add some classes so we can style it
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")") // move it into position
   .call(xAxis); // finally, add the axis to the visualisation


    vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
}
```

it should works

Comment: but when you load it the first time is clean?

Comment: yes it is fine the first few times with and w/o doing document.getElementById("#visualisation").innerHTML = ""; It only messes up after some 2-3 time of refreshing the graph with new data

Comment: it's unique,i have checked.here is sample example have a look.http://bigquerymashup.appspot.com/ajaxPage Try with word "the,and,i,and,the" one at a time.

Comment: @jade ok... see my edit (the bug is fixed but is without animation)

Comment: I cannot test your code. The problem is that you append every time the g.axis. So, instead to remove, try to append only if is the first time.