# NVD3, Clear svg before loading new chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have several different `NVD3` charts that I call upon in the same svg.
I use buttons to call functions, each containing a new chart that uses its own data.

Is there a way to clear my single svg without deleting it?
I wish to press a button to call my chart, but clear the svg before the new chart is loaded.

It's not an issue when using the kind of chart... calling two `multibarhorizontal` charts, for example, just updates the shapes, which is fine.
The problem is loading two different charts, like a line and a bar.

**EDIT** - The answers must be something like d`3.select("svg").remove()` but that just deletes the svg. I only want to clear it.

Comment: Have you tried `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()`?

Comment: That's the answer, it works, thanks Lars Kotthoff.

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Comment: if "chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);" was enabled, the old guideline remains even though the plot has been removed, anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can select all the elements below the SVG with the `"svg > *"` selector, i.e. to remove all of those, do

```
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
```

Comment: how would i remove the relevant tooltip that accompanies the chart? it just seems to append more tooltips every time i draw a new chart

Comment: @FinbarMaginn That entirely depends on how you've implemented the tooltip. I suggest you ask a separate question about this.

Answer (score 39):

This works for me:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are developing a dashboard having multiple widget showing different d3 charts then use the following

```
d3.selectAll("#d3-donutChart > *").remove();
```

this will only clear the specific chart, not all the svg's in the webpage.

Add this line just after subscribing to data in angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need.

```
svg.text('')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one that worked for me.

d3.selectAll("svg").remove();

Answer (score 0):

after create button put this code

```
$("svg").remove()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
For Re-Drawing the D3 Graphs by clearing the existing sketch and updating.
<body>
...
<input name="reDraw" type="button" value="Re-Draw" onclick="reDraw('data2.csv')" />
...

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

//d3.select('#chart svg')

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var updateData = function(getData){

    d3.selectAll('svg > g > *').remove();

    d3.csv(getData, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
      });

      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
      x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Population");

      var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "state")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      state.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

    });

}

updateData('data1.csv');

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this above code with data1.csv and data2.csv in your folder.
Thanks,

Comment: The question was answered sufficiently two years ago. This really doesn't add anything.

Comment: d3.selectAll('svg > g > *').remove();

Comment: This is the actual answer buddy 
    d3.selectAll('svg > g > *').remove();