# Rendering new graph data adds new graph instead of replacing existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, flask

I'm using Flask to build a D3 visualization and am requesting user data from a form using JQuery and D3.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    d3.json("{{ url_for('crew') }}")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .post($(this).serialize(), function(error, graph) {
```

When the user chooses data and presses Submit, a graph shows. The problem is that when Submit is pressed again, another graph appears on top of the old one.  I need to refresh before resubmitting the form.

```
@app.route('/crew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def crew():
    form = CrewForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('crews/', form.filename.data))

    return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `json` callback method clear the previous chart using either `jQuery` or `d3` method. Take a look at this link it might help you. [NVD3, Clear svg before loading new chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452112/nvd3-clear-svg-before-loading-new-chart)

Comment: This worked, thank you! I added `d3.selectAll("svg > *).remove();` and it clears the graph before adding the new one :)