# How to clear canvas for each update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my first ionic web app. I should do some charts so I decided to use d3.js and tree.js. I added the possibility to visualize my data with different type of chart. The problem appears when I draw in the same canvas different charts so I suppose that I have to clear the canvas before each update. This is my code:

```
// Some operations

var canvas = this.components.toArray()[idItem].nativeElement;

this.barChart = new Chart(canvas, {

  type: type,
  data: {
          labels: keys,
          datasets: [{
                      label: label,
                      data: values,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                      borderWidth: 1
                    }]
        },
  options: {
            scales: {
                      yAxes:  [{
                                ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                        }
                              }]
                    }
            }
  });
```

Searching on the web ([How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)) I tried to add these lines:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

but I still have the problem.

[Demonstration of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxrtf.gif)

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the official d3.js API to [clear a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452112/nvd3-clear-svg-before-loading-new-chart).
It's violent to clear canvas by web api, and may cause the problem.